# Amazon Certificate Manager compatibility

Tags: amazon-web-services

I wanted to know that with how many services rather with what all services I can use the certificates provided by Amazon Certificate Manager...

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to understand the ACM compatibility, we need to understand **Public Certificates** and **Private Certificates**.

- Public certificates identify resources on the public internet, while
   Private certificates identify resources on private networks.

ACM (AWS Certificate Manager) enables to handle both the public and private certificates.

One can use public and private ACM certificates with the following AWS services:
    
• **Elastic Load Balancing** 
    
• **Amazon CloudFront** 
    
• **Amazon API Gateway**
    
• **AWS Elastic Beanstalk** 
    
• **AWS CloudFormation** – Support is currently limited to public certificates that use email validation.

For more details on using ACM, refer the below link:
[ACM FAQS](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/)